# How to get value from <select><option> dropdown menu in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I made a dropdown menu. I want to dynamically set the default value. When the user changes the value I want a method to fire in the component controller and log the new value.

This dynamically sets the default value and shows all of the options. When the user changes the option the method `onChange()` fires. The problem is that the method logs the `<select>`, not the `<option>`.

```html
<form>
   <select (change)="onChange($event.target)" style="padding: 10px; font-size: 12pt;">
       <option *ngFor="let number of numbers" [selected]="number==clipInMovieWatching">Watch clip: {{number}}</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

```js
onChange(event: any) {
    console.log(event);
}
```

Result logged:

```
<select _ngcontent-keh-c129 style=​"padding:​ 10px;​ font-size:​ 12pt;​">​…​</select>​
```

All of the options are logged, not the option that the user selected.

`console.log(event.target)` logs `undefined`.

`console.log(event.target.target)` throws an error `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')`.

I tried using Material `mat-select`:

```html
<mat-form-field>
   <mat-select>
      <mat-option (onSelectionChange)="selectClip($event)" *ngFor="let number of numbers" [value]="number">Watch clip: {{number}}</mat-option>
   </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

```js
selectClip(event: any) {
    console.log(event.source.value);
}
```

This logs the option that the user selected. But the dropdown menu doesn't show the default option. The [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api) shows a property `selected`:

```
selected: MatOption | MatOption[]

The currently selected option.
```

but I can't get it to work.

Also, `mat-select` shows only four options. How can I make it show all the options?

Comment: You need to add the value on the option. `<option *ngFor="let number of numbers" [value]="number"></option>`.  Then you can access it on the event `event.target.value`

Comment: Jason White, `console.log(event.target)` logs `undefined`. `console.log(event.target.value` throws an error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')".

Comment: on change pass the whole event `<select (change)="onChange($event)">`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```js
console.log(event.target.value);
```

Comment: `console.log(event.target)` logs `undefined`. `console.log(event.target.value` throws an error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')".

Answer (score 1):

The mistake was that in the HTML view I had `(change)="onChange($event.target)` or `(change)="onChange($event.target.value)`. That throws the `undefined` error. The correct code is `(change)="onChange($event)"`. Then in the controller `console.log(event.target.value);`.

```html
<form>
   <select (change)="onChange($event)" style="padding: 10px; font-size: 12pt;">
       <option *ngFor="let number of numbers" [value]="number" [selected]="number==clipInMovieWatching">Watch clip: {{number}}</option>
   </select>
</form>
```

```js
onChange(event: any) {
  console.log(event.target.value);
}
```

`[value]="number"` helps but isn't essential. Without this it logs `Watch clip: 14`. With this code it logs `14`.